# CSharp getting path from user input and handle spaces

Tags: c#, .net, path, spaces, directoryinfo

Good morning,
first of all I've searched for it but I don't have found the answer and after many tries I'm here hoping for an answer (also a link to a resource!)

I'm trying to get a path via user input (Console Application) and but I'll get the "illegal characters" error when I paste a path with a space in a folder.

I've tried with something like that:

```
DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo(Console.ReadLine());
var files = path.GetFiles();
```

But I'll get error If paste `c:\some\path\pasted with spaces`

I've tried to replace the character with the `String.Replace()`

I don't know how to get something like `@"c:\some\path\enterd with space"`

What can I do?

Comment: Put the value of the path into a var and escape it so it becomes "C:\\some\\path\\entered with space"

Comment: It's not working, or maybe I'm not able to understand it. I have stored the   `Console.ReadLine()` inside a string called dir and then replaced the '\' character to '\\'. Still getting the same error. I feel so dumb

Comment: If you do a readline the string probably contains `\r\n` at the end. Try a `path.Trim()`

Comment: @andrepogg - Hello. I've posted an answer that works locally. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below to escape the contents of what is read in. Also add a check to ensure that the path is valid. The below works in a test project with local path C:\TS Space

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Path");
            var dirPath = @"" + Console.ReadLine();

            if (Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                var path = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
                var files = path.GetFiles();
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I've also added a `String.Replace("\"", "")` to the **dirPath** so if someone will drag the folder inside the console, everything will work fine

Answer (score 0):

The `@` symbol marks the string as a [Verbatim string Literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) - anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.

It would make sure that these two strings are treated as the same:

```
"D:\\Books\\DaVinciCode.txt"
```

is the same as

```
@"D:\Books\DaVinciCode.txt"
```

Without the `@` symbol in the immediately above string, the compiler will think that you are trying to escape the letters 'B' and 'D' thus throwing you compile time error - Unrecognized escape sequence as, 'B' and 'D' are not valid escape sequences.

and handling spaces will be taken care of by creating the path as :

```
 string filePath;
 Console.WriteLine("Enter Path: ");
 filePath = @""+Console.ReadLine();
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
 Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
```